# connect my chatbot to QnA in Language Studio

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to migrate from qnamaker.ai to language studio (LS). my current config file has kbId listed but, I don't see the kbId under the prediction url in Language Studio.

current file has:

```
"id": "GeneralITQNA",
                    "kbId": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "endpointKey":
```

So what should it have now to connect to QnA in LS? Do I need to use the 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'?

Is there an example of this such as seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js

[image]

[image]

OR here  https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/samples/csharp/assistants/virtual-assistant/VirtualAssistantSample/cognitivemodels.json

[image]

Thanks ahead of time for any help or direction!

Comment: The new language resources in Azure need to be configured differently. See this new [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/12.customQABot) for an example of how to connect.

Comment: I may just be being a noob, but I don't see anything making use of LanguageEndpointKey or LanguageEndpointHostName in the node modules folder.  Is there any sample like the one you shared available for node/js ?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/12.customQABot)

Comment: This should be posted and accepted as answer, extremely useful for eveyone looking and even more now that old QnA is no longer enabled for creation and people need to start with language !